# When projectile hits two "monsters" the didBeginContact method crashes. I know why but i don't know how to avoid it

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sprite, collision-detection

So I have this code from the tutorial:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    // 1
    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody?
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody?
    var body: SKPhysicsBody

    //contact.bodyB.node!.physicsBody!.allContactedBodies().count


        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
            firstBody = contact.bodyA
            secondBody = contact.bodyB
            println("1 = A, 2 = B")
        } else {
            firstBody = contact.bodyB
            secondBody = contact.bodyA
            println("2 = A, 1 = B")
        }



        // 2
        if ((firstBody!.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Monster != 0) &&
            (secondBody!.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Projectile != 0)) {

                for var c = 1; c <= contact.bodyB.node!.physicsBody!.allContactedBodies().count; c++ {
                    projectileDidCollideWithMonster(firstBody!.node as! SKSpriteNode, monster: secondBody!.node as! SKSpriteNode)

                }
                secondBody!.node?.removeFromParent()
        }
}

func projectileDidCollideWithMonster(projectile:SKSpriteNode, monster:SKSpriteNode) {
    println("Hit")
    changeScore(1)
    changeAmo(true)
    projectile.removeFromParent()
    monster.removeFromParent()
}
```

Then what is happening is that a projectile sometimes hit TWO monsters at once.

When this happens - didBeginContact method crashes saying that secondBody is nil.

After a thorough research I found out the reason:

when projectile collides with two other nodes at once - this method runs two times. After the first run - if gets bodyA as projectile, bodyB as a monster - passes them on to `projectileDidCollideWithMonster` and it removes them both. then it runs immediately again but at that moment projectile doesn't exist anymore and it crashes not able to assign it's node.

I have no idea how to overcome this:( any suggestions, please?

SOLUTION: Thanks to ideas below i did some changes.

added and array and a trigger at the top of the class:

```
    var bodiesToBeRemoved = [SKSpriteNode]()
    var shouldRemoveBodies = false
```

and did these modifications:

```
 func projectileDidCollideWithMonster(projectile:SKSpriteNode, monster:SKSpriteNode) {
 /* Called when collisions is detected and collided nodes are passed to it */
    //score and stuff
    println("Hit")
    changeScore(1)
    changeAmo(true)

    //collect the nodes to be removed
    bodiesToBeRemoved.append(projectile)
    bodiesToBeRemoved.append(monster)

    //change the trigger to remove collected nodes later on
    shouldRemoveBodies=true

}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    //check the trigger
    if shouldRemoveBodies == true {
        println("\(bodiesToBeRemoved.count)")
        //remove collected nodes
        for var i = 0; i<bodiesToBeRemoved.count; i++ {
            bodiesToBeRemoved[i].removeFromParent()
        }

        //reset array
        bodiesToBeRemoved.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        //reset the trigger
        shouldRemoveBodies = false
    } else {
        //do nothing:)
    }

}
```

Comment: I haven't really kept up to date with swift, but the ideas are usually language agnostic.  More than likely you are running some kind of event loop?  If so, you should mark the object for deletion if it collided, but not delete until after everything that needed to be checked was handled.

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond thank you! You and "talrnu" (below) gave me same direction and i made it work:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of removing your projectile immediately, just mark it for removal (e.g. by setting a boolean flag, or adding it to some collection if it's not already in the collection). Then later, before the next physics check (e.g. at the end of this frame), go through and remove all projectiles marked for removal.

Comment: yes that's a good idea about the end of the frame. what is the method which is called at the end of the frame? is there one?

Comment: thanks! i've updated my answer based on your suggestion:)

Answer (score 0):

Just check it's nil or not better than check every nodes's mark.

```
func removeNodeFromPhysicsBody(ps: SKPhysicsBody){
    if (ps.node != nil){
        ps.node?.removeFromParent()
    }
}

func wallDidCollideWithMeteor(wall:SKPhysicsBody, meteor:SKPhysicsBody) {
    removeNodeFromPhysicsBody(wall)
    removeNodeFromPhysicsBody(meteor)
}
```